# Getting claims in identity server using resource owner password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

I am using identity server 4 for authentication using grant type as 'ResourceOwnerPassword'. I am able to authenticate the user but not able to get claims related to user. So how can I get those ?

Below is my code

**Client**

Startup.cs

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ApiName = "api1"
            });
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Authentication(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:5000");

            // request token
            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret");
            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(model.Email, model.Password, "api1");

            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
            }
// Here I am not getting the claims, it is coming Forbidden
            var extraClaims = new UserInfoClient(disco.UserInfoEndpoint);
            var identityClaims = await extraClaims.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
            if (!tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(identityClaims.Json);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n");
}
```

Server
Startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients(Configuration))
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddProfileService<IdentityProfileService>()
                .AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Config.cs

```
 public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfigurationRoot Configuration)
        {
            // client credentials client
            return new List<Client>
            {

                // resource owner password grant client
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "ro.client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,


                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt

                }

            };
        }

public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
            };
        }
```

But when I check my access token in jwt.io there I can see the claims But why I am not able to get in the controller ?

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `UserInfoEndpoint`, as per your example, but you can also get additional claims if you define your `ApiResource` as requiring them.

For example, rather than just defining your `ApiResource` like you are:

```
new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
```

You can use the expanded format and define what `UserClaims` you'd like to have when getting an access token for this scope.
For example:

```
new ApiResource
{
    Name = "api1",
    ApiSecrets = { new Secret(*some secret*) },
    UserClaims = {
        JwtClaimTypes.Email,
        JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumber,
        JwtClaimTypes.GivenName,
        JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName,
        JwtClaimTypes.PreferredUserName
    },
    Description = "My API",
    DisplayName = "MyApi1",
    Enabled = true,
    Scopes = { new Scope("api1") }
}
```

Then in your own implementation of the `IProfileService` you will find that calls to `GetProfileDataAsync` have a list of what claims are requested in the context (`ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes`). Given that list of what's been asked for, you can then add any claims you like - however you like - to the `context.IssuedClaims` that you return from that method. These will then be a part of the access token.

If you only want certain claims by specifically calling the UserInfo endpoint though, you'll want to create an `IdentityResource` definition and have that scope included as part of your original token request.
For example:

```
new IdentityResource
{
    Name = "MyIdentityScope",
    UserClaims = {
        JwtClaimTypes.EmailVerified,
        JwtClaimTypes.PhoneNumberVerified
    }
}
```

But your first problem is following the other answer here so you don't get 'forbidden' as the response to the UserInfo endpoint!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the token along the request, when calling the UserInfoEndpoint. Try this:

```
var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(doc.UserInfoEndpoint, token);

var response = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
var claims = response.Claims;
```

[official docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/endpoints/userinfo.html#userinfo-endpoint)